# String matching and replace

Tags: python, string, string-matching

I have a text file like this and i want in implement in python

```
Enter the Username"<Username>" and phonenumber"<phonenumber>"
Enter the origin"<origin>" and destination"<destination>"
Examples:
 | Username | phonenumber | origin | destination|
 | JOHN | 40256786 | NYC | LONDON |
```

i want to replace the string which are in <> and replace with actual data, and my output will look like this :

```
Enter the Username "JOHN" and phonenumber "40256786"
Enter the origin "NYC" and destination "LONDON"
```

Comment: You example is a dict, a pandas dataframe, ...?

Comment: it is a list , as i read the data from textfile

Comment: Can you replace the delimiters '<' and '>' by only '$'? or '{' and '}'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Try:

```
import re

text = []
data = []
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    line = ''
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('Examples'):
            break
        text.append(line)
    text = ''.join(text)
    headers = re.split('\s*\|\s*', fp.readline())[1:-1]
    for line in fp:
        values = re.split('\s*\|\s*', line)[1:-1]
        data.append(dict(zip(headers, values)))

for d in data:
    print(re.sub(r'\<(?P<key>[^>]*)\>', lambda x: d[x.group('key')], text))
```

Output:

```
Enter the Username"JOHN" and phonenumber"40256786"
Enter the origin"NYC" and destination"LONDON"
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use plenty of text processors to substitute text by variables: `string.Template` (`$`), `format strings` (`{ }`), `Jinja2` (`{{ }}`). If you can, change your delimiter:

Here an example of format strings:

```
text = '''\
Enter the Username "{Username}" and phonenumber "{phonenumber}"
Enter the origin "{origin}" and destination "{destination}"\
'''

data = {'Username': 'John', 'phonenumber': '40256786',
        'origin': 'NYC', 'destination': 'LONDON'}

print(text.format(**data))
```

Output:

```
Enter the Username "John" and phonenumber "40256786"
Enter the origin "NYC" and destination "LONDON"
```

Comment: this cant help me , all are (text and data)  in a single text file only.

Comment: So create a sample with all data inside a single block.

Comment: yes i can , but i can not change the delimiter and this format (| Username | phonenumber | origin | destination|
 | JOHN | 40256786 | NYC | LONDON |)

Comment: Ok update your post with a real sample, it should not be so difficult. I hope :)

Comment: This is what my real sample, i have more 6 lines i have reduced it.

Comment: Data and list are separated by the word `Examples:`?

Comment: yes, Everything in single notepad file (.txtfile)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to split each line by the delimiting character |.  Then you can set the variables for the string accordingly.

```
sample_line = '| JOHN | 40256786 | NYC | LONDON |'
sample_line = sample_line.split('|')

data = {
    'Username':     sample_line[1],
    'phonenumber':  sample_line[2],
    'origin':       sample_line[3],
    'destination':  sample_line[4]
    }

text = '''\
Enter the Username "{Username}" and phonenumber "{phonenumber}"
Enter the origin "{origin}" and destination "{destination}"\
'''

print(text.format(**data))
```

Alternatively, you should be able to use something like csv.reader

Comment: Thanks for the help !! but  for me , "Sample_line and text "  are having in a single list .